# average sql query in python output decimal not integer

Tags: python, mysql, sql

[code link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBTz.jpg)

I want to output like integer.Btw in my database table my values are integer.

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta 

mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user="user",passwd="",database="test")

sessionID= "SE311"
datetime1=datetime.datetime(2020,5,19,22,40,00)

for loop in range(4):

    sqlform = "SELECT AVG(attentionP) FROM attentionstudent WHERE sessionID=%s AND min=%s"
    datetime1=datetime1+timedelta(minutes=1)

    data_tuple=(sessionID,datetime1)

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sqlform,data_tuple)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(records)
```

Comment: Could you provide some minimal working code that produces the result or error in question? That way we can copy and paste and test it out.

Comment: I added. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I think you should also include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE attentionstudent` into the question. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think if you're already storing as integer into the table, you'll always be getting round numbers without decimal. For example if your `AVG` suppose to be something like `1.91` and you store that value into a field with integer datatype, it will be stored as either `1` or `2` (if you have rounding) and that means all your output will be appending zero decimals only.